# iOS ad-hoc deployment

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

With apples ad-hoc deployment option for testing purposes, I understand there is a 100 device limit.

I was wondering, before I purchase a developer licence, is there any limitation on how long the ad-hoc apps can be used for, I know using test flight had a 30 day limitation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The app will be valid until the distribution certificate used to sign it expires, at which point it won't run. If memory serves, Apple distribution certificates for non-enterprise developer accounts have an expiration of one year. [Source.](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as long as it is there on your device. There is no time limit for same.

Comment: I do not have source. But few app developed using development profile are still present on my device and working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Well you can actually submit a beta test build on the App Store and invite to test it anyone, without needing to add their devices UDID on your provisioning profile...

You just need to pass the app validation to make the app available for public testing via Apple's Testflight